# My AJAX pagination with PHP is not working fine

Tags: php, ajax, pagination

I am trying to do AJAX pagination with filtering using PHP but pagination is not working, data is loaded on the page as required and filtering also is fine but when click page, no response..

MY PHP CODE WITH PAGINATION QUERY

```
        if(isset($_POST['category'])) {

    // Filter query
    $query ='';
$seller_filter = isset($_POST['level']) ? $_POST['level'] : '';
$sub_filter = isset($_POST['sub']) ? $_POST['sub'] : '';
$price_filter = isset($_POST['price']) ? $_POST['price'] : '';
$search_filter = isset($_POST['search']) ? $_POST['search'] : '';
$condition = htmlspecialchars(trim(strip_tags(stripslashes(stripcslashes($search_filter)))));
// Default limit
$limit = isset($_POST['per-page']) ? $_POST['per-page'] : 3;

// Default offset
$offset = 0;
$current_page = 1;
if(isset($_POST['page-number'])) {
    $current_page = (int)$_POST['page-number'];
    $offset = ($current_page * $limit) - $limit;
}

    $query .= "SELECT tag_name, room, sellers.seller_id,sellers.image,price,sellers.category_id,sellers.type,sellers.badge,categories.category, 
                COUNT(DISTINCT comments.user_id) AS total, ROUND(AVG(rating),1) AS rate,AVG(odds) AS odda FROM sellers 
                INNER JOIN categories ON sellers.category_id=categories.id 
                LEFT JOIN comments ON sellers.seller_id=comments.seller_id 
                LEFT JOIN posts ON sellers.seller_id=posts.seller_id
                LEFT JOIN keywords ON sellers.seller_id=keywords.seller_id
                WHERE category = :cat";
            if(!empty($seller_filter)){
                $query .=" AND sellers.badge = :bagt ";
            }else 
            if(!empty($sub_filter)){
                $query .=" AND sellers.type = :celt ";
            }else 
            if(!empty($price_filter)){
                $query .=" AND sellers.price BETWEEN $price_filter";
            }else 
            if(!empty($condition)){
                $query .=" AND sellers.room LIKE '%".$condition."%'";
                $query .=" OR tag_name LIKE '%".$condition."%'";
            }else 
            if(!empty($sub_filter) && !empty($seller_filter) && !empty($condition)) {
                $query .=" AND sellers.type = :celt AND sellers.badge = :bagt AND (sellers.room LIKE '%".$condition."%' OR tag_name LIKE '%".$condition."%') ";
            }

        $query .=" GROUP BY sellers.seller_id ";
        $query .=" ORDER BY rate DESC";
        $query .=" LIMIT $limit";

            $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
            $statement->bindParam(':cat',$_POST['category']);
            if(!empty($seller_filter)){
                $statement->bindParam(':bagt',$seller_filter);
            }else 
            if(!empty($sub_filter)){
                $statement->bindParam(':celt',$sub_filter);
            }
            $statement->execute();
            $statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //PDO::FETCH_OBJ
            $result = $statement->fetchAll();
            if($result) { 
                foreach($result as $product){

                $paged_products = array_slice($product, $offset, $limit);
                    // Define total products
                    $total_products = count($product);
                    // Get the total pages rounded up the nearest whole number
                    $total_pages = ceil( $total_products / $limit );
                    // Determine whether or not pagination should be made available.
                    $paged = $total_products > count($paged_products) ? true : false;
                    ?>
                    <div class="card col-sm-3 me-1 mt-3 product-wrapper"  style="width:12.7rem;height: 22rem;">
                                <?php echo '<a href=products.php?category='.preg_replace('#[-]+#', '-', trim($product['category'])).'&room='.preg_replace('#[-]+#', '-', trim($product ['room'])).'&seller_id='.preg_replace('#[-]+#', '-', trim($product ['seller_id'])).'>
                        <img src="../seller/' .htmlspecialchars($product ['image']).'" class="img-top  img-fluid bg-light" alt="...">
                        </a>';?> 
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="row border-bottom">
                            <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-primary w-50 position-absolute top-1 start-50 translate-middle">
                                <?php
                            if($product ['badge'] == '0') {
                                echo htmlspecialchars('NEW');
                            } elseif($product ['badge'] == '1') {
                                echo htmlspecialchars('Level 1');
                            } elseif($product ['badge'] == '2') {
                                echo htmlspecialchars('Level 2');
                            } else {
                                echo htmlspecialchars('PRO');
                            }
                ?> seller</span>
                                <h5 class="card-title text-center fw-bolder fs-5 mt-3"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($product ['room']);?></h5>
                                <p class="text-center text-decoration-none text-dark"  style="font-size:1rem;" ><?php echo htmlspecialchars($product ['category']);?></p>
                                <p class="text-danger"><i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i><?php echo htmlspecialchars($product ['rate']);?>
                                    <span class="text-end fw-light text-dark">(<?php echo htmlspecialchars($product ['total']);?>)</span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <p class="card-title text-start fw-bolder text-decoration-none text-dark" style="font-size:0.7rem;">STARTING AT
                            <span class="text-start fw-bolder text-decoration-underline" style="font-size:.8rem;">US &dollar;<?php echo htmlspecialchars($product ['price']);?></span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            <?php }if ($paged) {
                $query = isset($_POST) ?  'data-query="' . http_build_query($_POST) . '"' : '';
            ?>
            <nav class="col-md-12 mt-3" >
                <ul class="pagination">
                    <li class="page-item <?php echo $current_page === 1 ? 'disabled' : ''; ?>">
                      <a class="page-link" href="#" data-page-number="<?php echo $current_page - 1; ?>" <?php echo $query; ?> >
                        <span>«</span>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                <?php
                for($page_number = 1; $page_number <= $total_pages; $page_number++) { ?>
                    <li class="page-item <?php echo isset($_POST['page-number']) && $_POST['page-number'] == $page_number ? 'active' : ''; ?>"><a class="page-link" href="#" data-page-number="<?php echo $page_number; ?>" <?php echo $query; ?>><?php echo $page_number; ?></a></li>
                <?php } ?>
                    <li class="page-item <?php echo $current_page === (int)$total_pages ? 'disabled' : ''; ?>">
                      <a class="page-link" href="#" data-page-number="<?php echo $current_page + 1; ?>" <?php echo $query; ?>>
                        <span>»</span>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <?php  }
            }
            else {
                echo '<div class="text-danger display-1">OOPS! NOTHING IS HERE YET!</div>';
            }
    }
```

AJAX QUERY

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        load_data();
        function load_data(category='<?php echo $_GET['category'];?>',query='',page_number){
        $.ajax({
            method:"POST",
            url:"producta.php",
            data:{'category':category,'page-number':page_number,'query':query},
            success: function(data){
                $('#all-products').html(data);
            }
        })
    }
    $(document).on('click', '.page-link', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var page_number = $(this).data('page-number');
            var query;
            
            if( $(this).data('query') ) {
                query = '?' + $(this).data('query');
            }
            else {
                query = '';
            }
            
            $.post('producta.php'+query, {'page-number' : page_number,'query' : query}, function(data){
                $('#all-products').html(data);
            })
        })
$(document).on('submit', '#filter-form', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    
    var form = $(this);
    
    $.post('producta.php?category=<?php echo $_GET['category'];?>', $(form).serialize(), function(data){
        $('#all-products').html(data);
    })
    
})
});
```

Please can someone help me to point out what I am doing wrong with the pagination? I have checked out other question at stackoverflow but I can't actually figure out what is the problem in my query. When I click page link, the page goes blank. No data gets displayed. I think the problem is in my pagination and Ajax queries but I can't figure out. I need a second mind to help out

Comment: Your code is open to [SQL Injection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). Never concatenate user input directly into SQL queries! You should be using [parameterized prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). What debugging have you done? Is the AJAX request sent when you click on your pagination links? What is the response?

Comment: I didnt post full code here. I have a prepared querry for all those input and params are bound

Comment: What's the point in posting code which is not representative of your code? You did not answer my questions about your debugging efforts.

Comment: @user1191247 how do you want me to help you exactly?

Comment: The first block of code posted is unsafe concatenated SQL. We read your first comment as “I have safe prepared statements in my real code, this is just a sample”. The question is, why should we troubleshoot your sample code if you won’t be using it? If it isn’t relevant, that’s fine, too, but it shouldn’t be posted then

Comment: What sql database are you using?
Start by debugging your query. 
I see no `select` en invalid `group by` and `order by` keywords

Comment: @ChrisHaas iI will snd the query. Let me edit the post. I sent that way because I thought guys will just understand how that query is

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed I am editing the question and sending the full query because I seriously need help in this

Comment: @user1191247 okay. let me try checking it out again.

Comment: @user1191247 currently I am getting this in the network tab    category: Football
page-number: 2
query:                                             but data on the page doesnt change. The same data displayed initially on the first page is displayed without a change

Comment: If it's running the same query, it will return the same output! If you have modified the query please update your question so it reflects the current state of your code.

Answer (score 0):

The first line of your PHP code checks:

```php
if(isset($_POST['category'])) {
```

but category is not being passed in your `$.post()` requests:

```js
$.post('producta.php'+query, {'page-number' : page_number,'query' : query}, function(data){
    $('#all-products').html(data);
})
```

Assuming that `category` is included in the string passed in `query` you could do something like:

```php
parse_str(ltrim($_POST['query'] ?? '', '?'), $queryArray);
$_POST = array_merge($queryArray, $_POST);
```

Instead of testing each of your inputs with `isset()` you can use the [null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op):

```php
$seller_filter = $_POST['level'] ?? '';
$sub_filter = $_POST['sub'] ?? '';
$price_filter = $_POST['price'] ?? '';
$search_filter = $_POST['search'] ?? '';
```

This line does not make sense and is no substituation for parameterizing:

```php
$condition = htmlspecialchars(trim(strip_tags(stripslashes(stripcslashes($search_filter)))));
```

You are still passing `$price_filter` and `$condition` directly into your query instead of using parameters. This is incredibly easy to exploit and should be corrected.

When building up your query, the last of the `else if` chain can never be reached, as `!empty($sub_filter)` would have been satisfied in the second condition in the chain. Perhaps each of these conditions should be independent `if` statements instead?

You have calculated `$offset` but are not passing it into your query:

```php
$offset = ($current_page * $limit) - $limit;

// missing offset
$query .=" LIMIT $limit";
```

You need to do a `COUNT` query based on the filter criteria to figure out what, if any, pagination is required.

This, and related code, makes no sense as you are already doing the pagination in SQL:

```php
$paged_products = array_slice($product, $offset, $limit);
```

The use of `htmlspecialchars()` here, and for similar lines, makes no sense:

```php
echo htmlspecialchars('NEW');
```

There are probably other issues, but hopefully this is enough to get you heading in the right direction.